# How to convert a string into a float when reading from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey guys so I have a text file that I am trying to read from and receive every number string
and convert it into a float. But every time I try it, it says "cannont convert string to float". Why is this happening? Thanks!

```
try:
    input_file = open("Dic9812.TFITF.encoded.txt","r")
    output_fileDec = open("Dic9812.TFITF.decoded.txt","w")
    output_fileLog = open("Dic9812.TFITF.log.txt","w")
except IOError:
    print("File not found!")

coefficientInt = input("Enter a coefficient: ")
coefficientFl = float(coefficientInt)
constInt = input("Enter a constant: ")
constFl = float(constInt)

try:
    for line in input_file:
        for numstr in line.split(","):
            numFl = float(numstr)
            print(numFl)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

The file looks like this:

```
135.0,201.0,301.0
152.0,253.0,36.0,52.0
53.0,25.0,369.0,25.0
```

It ends up printing the numbers but at the end it says:
cannot convert string to float:

Comment: First, can you show an example of the file you're trying to parse?

Comment: Second, tell us on which line `cannont convert string to float` happens.

Comment: Are you *sure* there is `etc` in the file? Please post some *real* lines.

Comment: At the end there is an empty string (if the trailing comma is real).

Comment: Yes I just figured this out, apparently there was a trailing comma and I just took it off of the text file and everything works now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the end of the second line, you have a comma, so you have an empty string in the list. `float('')` raise an exception, hence your error:

```
for line in input_file:
    for numstr in line.split(","):
        if numstr:
            try:
                numFl = float(numstr)
                print(numFl)
            except ValueError as e:
                print(e)
```

As said in comments, avoid to catch `Exception` and try to have the minimum lines of code in a `try/except` to avoid silent errors.

Comment: You should just catch `ValueError`s, since catching any `Exception` could cause silent failures.

Comment: @2rs2ts Yep, fast copy/paste in fact... :)

Answer (score 0):

**Input `f`**

```
135.0,201.0,301.0
152.0,253.0,36.0,52.0
53.0,25.0,369.0,25.0
```

**Python `f.py`**

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    fs = [float(f) for f in line.split(",")]
    print fs
```

**Usage**

```
$ python f.py < f
```

**Output**

```
[135.0, 201.0, 301.0]
[152.0, 253.0, 36.0, 52.0]
[53.0, 25.0, 369.0, 25.0]
```